# PHP/MySQL structure record last 5 logins

Tags: php, mysql

Something is wrong with me and I cant think of a way how to record last 5 logins (date and IP address). I don't want to create 5 tables. 
I need the easiest way, please.

I dont want to store every login in the database and I dont want to delete the unnecessery logins.

Comment: Create a table like login_rec(login_id,datetime,IP) its done!

Comment: Why would there be 5 tables? :|

Comment: Create a single table with all the login detail you want.1st comment has your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db table:
id: primary_key AUTO_INCREMENT
date: timestamp
ip: varchar(15)

php:

```
$db->insert('login_logs', array(  
    'date' => gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s', now()),  
    'ip' => $ip  
));  
$db->query("DELETE FROM login_logs where id not in (SELECT id FROM login_logs WHERE 1 LIMIT 5)");
```

Comment: what? why delete? Bad idea

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? It means that you have a maximum of 5 entries in the table, seems quite sane to me.

Comment: the question says to record last 5 logins. not to show last 5 logins.

Comment: Oh man why extra load on DB Engine by deleting rows??? just insert and get last 5. And that's radiculous idea of deleting a record from table  while you do not need to do that

Comment: What about the extra load on the DB engine by storing an arbitrary number of rows (adding a new row every time a user logs in) and performing a full index or table scan for the order by? I think the cost of a single delete every time would have decreasing cost over the lifetime of the time, but like everything, ask the profiler

Comment: Good idea but I want to avoid the Delete part :D

Comment: @user2979496 there is nothing wrong with the delete part; you'll be saving yourself performance issues in the long run where you have had 100,000 logins. With this solution, you're only ever dealing with 5 rows. Much faster to query against.

Comment: Alright I will use this one. It's really nothing wrong with the delete thing. Thanks to @jhdxr

Comment: @Darkzaelus That's just not accurate. With an index on the last-logged-in-at column (which is monotonically increasing and thus does not create index fragmentation) and a SARGABLE query with an ordering on the last-logged-in-at with a limit, I would expect a table with 5 records and 5 million records to have approximately equivalent "performance". If this kind of extra performance is required (without all the other ACID properties or information retention), then a better solution is likely *not* use an RDBMS, but rather a [persisted] cache.

Comment: @Darkzaelus The last-logged-in-at column/index could also cover the user/IP columns, which would eliminate the need for an additional lookup into the primary data cluster/row. Modern databases engines are smart (even MySQL, for simple queries) and can perform *very* efficiently with the correct indices and queries - even as the amount of information grows.

Comment: @user2864740 the cache would definately work better, I agree. Apologies that I am misinformed. I had also forgotten that indexes can have ordering!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a single table with two columns:

- date
- IP address

Comment: I need last 5 .. I see you want me to limit my query to last 5 but if I record every login my db will crash with a milion entries for one night.

Comment: You get a million logins every night? You are Mark Zuckerberg and I claim my £10!

Answer (score -1):

1) Simple create a table with 3 column (Id, date and IP). Set Id column to auto_increment with primary key.

2) Record every login in that table

3) Use this query to return last 5 logins

```
select * from tblLogin order by id desc limit 5.
```

this will return last 5 logins.

Comment: I would order by over an indexed "logged on at" datetime column. The information  is required and provides ordering based on real information. (Surrogate PKs should *not* be treated as information!)

Comment: you are query last 5 logins, not RECORD last 5 logins.

Comment: Well @user2864740 you should also see what can cause performance impact by indexing date and indexing a id column. Which is better for query??? ask any expert and will have your answer. This is where logics are called.

Comment: Haha. Don't make me laugh about this "expert performance advice". With comments like that, there is no point trying to explain why an such an index here *won't be a problem*.

Comment: hahaahah saw your jealous. Better learn more baby

Comment: I'm not ["jealous"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jealous). Try a dictionary. As for the index, read up about [monotonically increasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). You may also benefit from taking a course on databases.

Comment: hahaahahah you better be a english teacher rather than a good programmer or dba lols. SOrry you cant be even an english teacher if you dont know jealous lols. forget debating.

Comment: ..and tomorrow I will have no memmory bcs the mysql crashed with a million rows for one night ;)